# WPF DataGrid - Transparent Horizontal Grid Lines except for bottom horizontal line of the last row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm not too familiar with C# or XAML, but I have a DataGrid that sets the Horizontal Grid Lines to be transparent. However, I would need to have the last row's bottom grid line of the DataGrid to be a solid line and not Transparent.

DataGrid is within a Grid and I tried setting the Border thickness value to be "0,0,0,1" on the off chance that it would work, but didn't.
Tried to add some conditional statements to check for the last row of the DataGrid, but the way the code is built, there's no particular way to determine if it is the last row.

Current Style for the DataGrid

```
<Style x:Key="OrderViewDataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode"  Value="Single"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#CDCDCD"/>
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource DatagridColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource OrderViewDatagridRowStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F6F6F6"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#CDCDCD"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"  Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode"  Value="Recycling" />
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing"  Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="EnableRowVirtualization" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="EnableColumnVirtualization" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

DataGrid

```
<Grid>
  <Grid>
    <Border>
      ...
    <Border/>
    <DataGrid>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
      <DataGrid.Columns/>
    <DataGrid/>
    <DataGrid>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
      <DataGrid.Columns/>
    <DataGrid/>
    <DataGrid>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
      <DataGrid.Columns/>
    <DataGrid/>
  <Grid/>
<Grid/>
```

I'm trying to see if there's a better way of implementing the one line at the bottom side of the last row without conditional xaml statements.

Comment: Are you talking about the last row being displayed, or the last row in the data?

Comment: the last row being displayed. All the rows are being displayed perfectly fine. It's the horizontal grid lines that I have a problem with. Currently it's set to transparent but I need it to be transparent except for the last row. I'm trying to get the bottom grid line of the last row to show.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              Background="White"
              BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
              DataContext="{Binding ElementName=win}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Tried to implement it, and it still has the bottom border missing. I also tried wrapping the 2nd grid within a Border, but the border seemed to shrink; needs resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap the datagrid itself in a border?

```
<Grid>
  <Border BorderBrush="#CDCDCD" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
  <DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      ...
    <DataGrid.Columns/>
  <DataGrid/>
<Border/>
<Grid/>
```

Comment: The DataGrid gets called each time a new row is built so I can't wrap it with a border. It'll give every row a bottom grid line, if I did so.